# Why did I take damage from landing my boat on a slab?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I wanted to create a "harbor" for my boats, and I read that slabs will not damage the boat if I sail onto it. But when I tested it out, I instantly died the minute the boat touched the slab. How do I fix it?

Here is a picture:

[image]

Comment: How much health did you have? Could it be you suffocated even just momentarily? Also consider using soul sand instead.

Comment: Just another reason why I never use boats except when I absolutely have to.

Comment: I had full health.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Minecraft 1.7.3, this issue has been resolved [MC-881](https://mojang.atlassian.net/browse/MC-881)

Answer (score 6):

From the Minecraft Wiki [page on Boats](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Boat):

> Running aground on slabs will inflict some amount of falling damage. The damage seems to be much worse the longer you've been in the boat. (Perhaps due to the bobbing motion at sea being counted as 'falling' distance, and cashing it all in at once). This bug is also triggered when exiting a boat while on Soul Sand.

So yes, this glitch may kill you, and unfortunately using other blocks like Soul Sand doesn't help the matter. All you can do is hope it gets fixed.

Comment: "Perhaps due to the bobbing motion at sea being counted as 'falling' distance, and cashing it all in at once" -- That was the problem probably.